# How to add diffrent facebook Secure Page Tab URL for each page in one app

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I try to create a facebook app for page tab each able to insert different "Secure Page Tab URL" for example

hxxps://fb.xxx.com/sub1 -----> page A

.
.
.

hxxps://fb.xxx.com/subX -----> page X

I try to use

```
function pageinstall() {
  FB.ui({
  method: 'pagetab',
  redirect_uri: 'https://www.xxx/test.php'
  }, function(response){});
}
```

But this method will insert only "Secure Page Tab URL" which filled in app setting page.

If it possible in javascript-SDK or php-SDK

Please suggest me.

Thank you,

Umpol

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible – you can only have one page tab URL per app.

If you want to show different content depending on what page the app is added to – then get the page id from the `signed_request` that is POSTed to your app on initial load into the iframe.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs#integrating
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found some apps they provide website service they can embeded different "Secure Page Tab URL" for each user automatically I dont' know how can they do.

Comment: Again, it is not possible to have more than one Secure Page Tab URL for one single app. If you want to serve content based on what page the app is embedded on, use the signed_request.

Comment: The PHP SDK has methods that handle all that for you already. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookPageTabHelper/5.0.0#get-page-id